# JButtons to adjust to size based on it's textual contents

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I am working on a project which requires creating a number of JButtons. Each of these buttons will enclose different characters; a few of which containing words. The problem is I cannot seem to find out how I can set a JButton to resize based on its textual contents.

Is there a method which does this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you want to change the text of the buttons *after* they are created, or will the text be set only once?

Comment: try button.setBorder(null); ?

Comment: resizing the button is the job of the layoutManager, not yours :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JButton.getPreferredSize()` will give you the size required to display the text and icon.
The Button will automatically update it's preferred size if you change the text/icon.

If the button is actually rendered in with its preferred size depends on the LayoutManager of its container.